# JFrame - JList specific actions depending on selection

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I created a list basically copying the 'ListDemo.java' from the oracle site. I included a picture of what I have.

```
public static class BackpackList extends JPanel implements ListSelectionListener {

    private JList list;
    private DefaultListModel listModel;

    private static final String useString = "Use";
    private JButton useButton;

    public BackpackList() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        listModel.addElement("Flashlight");
        listModel.addElement("Health potion");
        listModel.addElement("Snacks");

        //Create the list and put it in a scroll pane.
        list = new JList(listModel);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.setSelectedIndex(0);
        list.addListSelectionListener(this);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

        useButton = new JButton(useString);
        useButton.setActionCommand(useString);
        useButton.addActionListener(new UseListener());

        //Create a panel that uses BoxLayout.
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPane,
                                           BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        buttonPane.add(useButton);
        buttonPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        buttonPane.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));
        buttonPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        buttonPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));

        add(listScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    }

    class UseListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //This method can be called only if
            //there's a valid selection
            //so go ahead and remove whatever's selected.
            int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
            listModel.remove(index);

            int size = listModel.getSize();

            if (size == 0) { //Nobody's left, disable firing.
                useButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else { //Select an index.
                if (index == listModel.getSize()) {
                    //removed item in last position
                    index--;
                }

                list.setSelectedIndex(index);
                list.ensureIndexIsVisible(index);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {

            if (list.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
            //No selection, disable fire button.
                useButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else {
            //Selection, enable the fire button.
                useButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Question 1: I am setting up a backpack for a basic text based game. I want to set up specific actions depending on what item you have selected in the list. What would be the code to make it so the health potion would do something different than the snacks?

[image]

Question 2: How could I make it so it would say something along the lines of **"x2 Snacks"** if you have 2 snacks or **"x3 Snacks"** if you have 3 snacks, etc.

Comment: Is question 1 *really* a question?

Comment: @JoshM, I'm new to programming and I don't really know this.

Comment: @Radiodef: How can you say that?? Surely this is do-able. The JList can contain items say that utilize a comment interface, say Collectable, and you can use a Command Design Pattern to change actions that occur based on the type of object collected from the list. To the original poster, your current example wouldn't work very well since your JList just contains Strings. Instead you'll want to create classes for these objects that allow them to have behaviors that you'd like to elicit on collecting them.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's what I mean. Right now the OP is putting Strings in the list and the list needs to contain inventory objects that are defined elsewhere.

Comment: I unfortunately don't do much GUI in Java, I am only experienced in using JFrame/JPanel

Comment: Try taking a look at [Selecting Items in a List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#selection)

Comment: @Radiodef: sure, he needs to beef up his OOP structure of his program, but that doesn't mean that `"basically you can't do this with a JList"`. Again that statement is blatantly untrue and deserves calling out. If I had made that statement, I'd delete it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I guess 'this' requires more of a qualifier. What you can't do with a JList is anything more than manage a list. On the other hand you can use a JList to manage any kind of list of any kind of object. You can absolutely use a JList to manage a list of objects with abstract actions. But those objects are defined elsewhere and the JList doesn't have anything to do with their definitions and implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backpack needs to keep track of items that are defined elsewhere. JList can hold a list of any kind of object so what you need to do is create objects for the inventory items. Below shows an example using an enum:

```
public class InventoryManager {

    public enum InventoryItem {
        LIGHT("Flashlight") {
            boolean isOn;
            @Override public void doAction() {
                isOn = !isOn;
            }
            @Override public String toString() {
                return name;
            }
        },
        POTION("Health Potions") {
            @Override public void doAction() {
                Game.getPlayer().setHealth(Game.getPlayer().getHealth() + 25);
                remove(1);
            }
        },
        SNACK("Snacks") {
            @Override public void doAction() {
                Game.getPlayer().setEnergy(Game.getPlayer().getEnergy() + 10);
                remove(1);
            }
        };

        private final String name;
        private int quantity = 0;

        private InventoryItem(String n) {
            name = n;
        }

        public abstract void doAction();

        public void add(int q) {
            if ((quantity += q) < 0) quantity = 0;
        }

        public void remove(int q) {
            add(-q);
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            return name + " x" + quantity;
        }
    }

    public static InventoryItem[] getHeldItems() {
        EnumSet<InventoryItem> items = EnumSet.allOf(InventoryItem.class);

        Iterator<InventoryItem> it = items.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (it.next().quantity < 1) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }

        return items.toArray(new InventoryItem[items.size()]);
    }
}
```

The enum example is entirely static so there are some problems with actually doing it this way (I chose it primarily because it's the shortest code). But ultimately what you'll have is a superclass Item with abstract methods that the subclasses implement differently. Then you will populate the JList with the items held. When the user selects an item from the list, `list.getSelectedValue()` returns an Item object you can use in the game.

```
// or Item can be an interface classes implement

public abstract class Item {
    public void doAction() {
        Game.updateState();
    }
}

public class Light extends InventoryItem {
    boolean lighted;
    @Override public void doAction() {
        lighted = !lighted;
        super.doAction();
    }
}

public class Potion extends InventoryItem {
    @Override public void doAction() {
        player.hp++;
        super.doAction();
    }
}

public class Snack extends InventoryItem {
    @Override public void doAction() {
        player.energy++;
        super.doAction();
    }
}
```

The other way to do this is to use straight program logic, for example:

```
switch (list.getSelectedItem()) {
    case "Flashlight": {
        toggleFlashlight();
        break;
    }

    case "Health Potion": {
        usePotion();
        break;
    }

    case "Snack": {
        useSnack();
        break;
    }
}
```

But I have a feeling trying to do it all with logic like that will ultimately turn out to be more complicated.